# What is a DSS server for HP printers and where is it installed?

Tags: hp, printer

I'm working with some HP printers and I'm getting the error "DSS Authentication. Unexpected failure." I'm trying to locate the DSS server and trying to figure out what version the server is. Additionally I'm trying to find instructions on updating DSS server software.

Answer (score 1):

DSS stands for HP Digital Sending Software.  You can download a demo copy here:

http://h20293.www2.hp.com/portal/swdepot/displayProductInfo.do?productNumber=T1936AADEMO
Some product info can be found here:
http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/pscmisc/vac/us/en/en/network_software/dss_overview_new.html

It's used by multi function printers to scan docs to various network locations (folders, faxes, emails)

You should be able to find the server with a WMI query across your domain for installed software.

Comment: This is outside my normal course of activities, could you please be more specific about how to perform a WMI query. Thank you.